# ¿Cómo poner un footer debajo de un componente con float?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, float

Tengo un sticky footer al final de la web, pero en una página en la que tengo insertado un feed de Twitter no funciona como me gustaría. El footer atraviesa el feed de Twitter, no se ubica debajo.

Este es el código del texto y el feed de Twitter:

```
<div>   
    <div style="float:left;width:80%;padding-right:20px">
        La Plataforma de Prácticas Externas..
    </div>

    <div style="float:right;position:absolute;display:inline-block;">
        <a class="twitter-timeline" data-lang="es" data-width="300" data-height="800" data-theme="light" data-link-color="#2B7BB9" href="https://twitter.com/X?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by X</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Este es el código del footer:

```
<div  align="center" style="position: sticky;width: 100%;bottom: 0%;clear: both;padding-top: 20px;">
    <hr />
    <p class="small">Copyright &copy; <fmt:formatDate value="${date}" pattern="yyyy" /> Footer</b>
</div>
```

Y esta una imagen del resultado:

[image: resultado]

Lo que quiero conseguir es que el footer se ubique tras el final de la caja de Twitter. Esta es una **preview** de lo que quiero:

[image: preview]

**EDIT:**

Ya tengo el footer al final pero la caja de Twitter se sitúa debajo del texto, aquí dejo jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/5q4g3dbr/2/

Comment: ¿Sabes que hay un `tag` llamado [`footer`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_footer.asp)? Prueba `position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;`

Comment: Obtengo el mismo resultado con <footer>. Y con el absolute también obtengo el mismo resultado

Comment: Prueba a poner "position:relative" a la columna de twitter.

Comment: De esa forma la columna de Twitter se sitúa bajo el texto a la derecha y el footer está siempre visible al final de la pantalla, haciendo o no scroll

Comment: ¿Quieres que el footer este debajo de la columna de twitter?

Comment: Claro, quiero que esté al final de cualquier página, que siempre sea lo último de cada página

Comment: He añadido un jsfiddle de cómo me queda ahora mismo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De esta forma funciona como quiero:

```
<div style="float:left;width:70%;">
    La Plataforma de Prácticas Externas...
</div>

<div style="float:right;width:30%;">
    <a class="twitter-timeline" data-lang="es" data-width="300" data-height="800" data-theme="light" data-link-color="#2B7BB9" href="https://twitter.com/x?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by x</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</div>  


<div  align="center" style="width: 100%;bottom: 0;clear: both;padding-top: 20px;">
    <hr />
    <p class="small">Copyright &copy; <fmt:formatDate value="${date}" pattern="yyyy" /> Footer</b>
</div>
```

Comment: el atributo `align` esta desaconsejado hace ya unos cuantos años. Ahi lo importante es el `clear: both` que no deja que haya elementos flotantes a derecha e izquierda y por lo tanto el `footer` se posiciona debajo